# Flutterflow and Supabase: How do I filter one ListView in flutterflow based on the selected item in a parent ListView with data supplied by Supabase?

Tags: flutter, supabase

How do I filter one ListView in flutterflow based on the selected item in a parent ListView with data supplied by Supabase?

I have two tables in Supabase (singers, songs) that are linked by the Singer ID. In Flutterflow I have a ListView that has a backend query to the Singers. I want to add another ListView within the first ListView to display a list of the songs from the songs table. How would I filter the backend query on the second ListView to filter based on the selected item in the first ListView?

I tried to filter but cannot work out how best to do this. Within the first ListView i have multiple containers. There is a separate container containing the second ListView that I am attempting to bind to the Songs table filtered by the singer in the first ListView.

Note: I am using Flutterflow rather than native Flutter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've answered my own question.

Firstly when creating the songs table in Supabase I did not create the policy. Each table in Supabase needs a policy.

Next, edit the backend query on the second **ListView**. Add in a filter.

For **Field Name**, choose **Singer**, the ID in the Songs table that links to the Singers table.

For **Relation** choose **Equal To** For **Value Source** choose **From Variabl**e Then choose **ID** from the Singers table.

The filter knows that a particular singer is selected from the parent ListView and filters as such.